# Page Permission via Notion API

Tags: notion-api

Is there any way to provide permission to a particular user to a page using Notion API (curl)?

Tried multiple endpoints such as update etc , however nothing worked

```
private function grantFullAccessToUser($userEmail, $pageId)
{
    // Prepare the request data
    $url = 'https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/' . $pageId . '/permissions';
    $headers = [
        'Authorization: Bearer NOTION_TOKEN',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Notion-Version: 2021-05-13'
    ];
    $data = [
        'role' => 'editor',
        'user_id' => $userEmail
    ];

    // Send the request to grant access
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Handle the response
    if ($response) {
        // Access granted successfully
        echo 'Full access granted to user: ' . $userEmail;
            
    } else {
        // Access granting failed
        echo 'Failed to grant full access to user: ' . $userEmail;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured it out already, unfortunately there is no current way to change permissions on a page with the Notion api. I confirmed it with their support via email.

I did put in a feature request for it a few months ago and I would encourage you to do the same. I assume it won't be worked on until they get X amount of feature requests. Hope that helps!